# Compiling Python to a static lib and using pythoncore.lib

Tags: python, static, compilation, python-2.7, static-libraries

I'm trying to build Python 2.7 as a static single .lib file.

I've already made the following changes to the Python source code:

1. Change to "Release" mode.
2. Change all DLL projects to Static library (.lib) and set runtime library to /MT
3. Add preprocessor definition Py_NO_ENABLE_SHARED to python and pythoncore

I've managed to compile the pythoncore project to pythoncore.lib (about 11mb size),
but when trying to compile the python project I get the following linking errors:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __Py_ActivateActCtx referenced in function __PyImport_GetDynLoadFunc C:\Python-2.7.3_Source\PCbuild\pythoncore.lib(dynload_win.obj)
>       error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __Py_DeactivateActCtx referenced in function __PyImport_GetDynLoadFunc    C:\Python-2.7.3_Source\PCbuild\pythoncore.lib(dynload_win.obj)
>       error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __Py_hgidentifier referenced in function __PySys_Init C:\Python-2.7.3_Source\PCbuild\pythoncore.lib(sysmodule.obj)
>       error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __Py_hgversion referenced in function __PySys_Init    C:\Python-2.7.3_Source\PCbuild\pythoncore.lib(sysmodule.obj)
>       error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Py_GetBuildInfo referenced in function _Py_GetVersion    C:\Python-2.7.3_Source\PCbuild\pythoncore.lib(getversion.obj)

Can anyone help me?

Thanks,

Idan

-------------------- update -------------------------------------

I just managed to make it work.. if it would help anyone, these are the changes I made:

1. Add `Modules\getbuildinfo.c` to the pythoncore project.
2. In `PC\dl_nt.c` move this line `#ifdef Py_ENABLE_SHARED` from line 14 to line 79 (just above DllMain).

... and that's it!

You may now link to pythoncore.lib :)

Idan

Comment: just add getbuildinfo.c into pythoncore project is enough.