# Static link to Python C API with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-2010

I am working in an existing c++ project that builds a dll.
I am trying to call python using the C api. I can either use `#include <boost/python.hpp>` or just `#include <Python.h>` and my code works fine.

I have pointed the linker at the folder containing python27.lib (MyProject -> Properties -> ConfigurationProerties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories) and so I am expecting it to statically link to python.

My problem is that when I look using Dependency Walker, I see that my dll is depending on python27.dll.

This is a case where I genuinely want to static link to python.

I have done a lot of research and tried various preprocessor directives but no luck. Thank you for any help

Comment: Does Python provide static library? If not, no way to do it

Comment: Yes I can see the python27.lib file and pointed the linker at its directory.

Comment: File with extension lib doesn't mean it is a static lib file

Comment: Do you mean the .lib files are probably just stubs as in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297013/why-do-we-still-need-a-lib-stub-file-when-weve-got-the-actual-dll-implementat ? Thank you

Comment: yes. If DLL is also generated with the lib file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved as follows:

As pointed out by [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/631599/matt), the lib files shipped with Python are not static libraries but just stub files.

Therefore I downloaded the python source and built it. To make my project link I had to:

1. In the python project and all its dependencies, change Properties -> General -> ConfigurationType to Static library. For the executables (make_buildinfo and make_versioninfo), need to first build as executables once to get the .exe, and then build as static libraries to get the .lib files.
2. Do this: [Compiling Python to a static lib and using pythoncore.lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567210/compiling-python-to-a-static-lib-and-using-pythoncore-lib)
3. Set the preprocessor macro Py_NO_ENABLE_SHARED (make sure Py_ENABLE_SHARED is not set)
4. Copy pyconfig.h into the Python Include directory
5. Use the pure Python C API (give up using Boost Python, because it is dynamic linking to Python)
6. Add these lines into the cpp file before calling Py_Initialize():

   // These (or a subset of them) are necessary so that it uses the static linked python, and does not try to load python from a default location.
   Py_NoSiteFlag = 1; 
   Py_FrozenFlag = 1; 
   Py_IgnoreEnvironmentFlag = 1; 
   Py_SetPythonHome(""); 
   Py_SetProgramName("");
7. For 64 bit compilation, need to set Project Settings -> Configuration Properties -> Librarian -> General -> Target Machine for each project. Note that lib files get put in PCbuild\amd64 (not PCbuild)

Thank you